# Flex 4 Button state in a HGroup

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a HGroup with some buttons inside which is my application's menu.

```
<s:HGroup id="nav">
    <s:Button id="homeButton" label="Home" />
    <s:Button id="showroomButton" label="Showroom" />
    <s:Button label="Catalogue" />
    <s:Button label="Offers" />
    <s:Button label="My Account" />
    <s:Button label="My Orders" />
</s:HGroup>
```

What I want is when I click for example the #homeButton to change it's state to "over", become disabled and reset all other buttons to the "up" state.

I've written this function

```
    private function resetNavState():void {
        for(var i:int = 0,ii:int = nav.numChildren-1;i<ii;i++) {
        Button(nav.getChildAt(i)).mouseEnabled = true;
        Button(nav.getChildAt(i)).skin.setCurrentState("up",true);
    }
}
```

And then on the homeButton click handler for example i use

```
protected function homeButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    resetNavState();
    currentState = "home";
    homeButton.skin.setCurrentState("over",true);
    homeButton.mouseEnabled = false;

}
```

I resets the states of the #nav buttons but it doesn't change the state of the pressed button.

Any ideas?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to place your buttons in a in a `<s:ButtonBar />` control rather than the HGroup.

Comment: I'd use a ButtonBar but I don't want to use viewstacks but states. Also I find it more difficult to skin a ButtonBar...

Comment: You're not limited to using ViewStacks with ButtonBars, you can execute whatever logic you want by handling the ButtonBar's change event. Why do you find them difficult to style?

Comment: After reading more carefully the docs I've finally understood how it works :) Thnx